# Query Formula and Multiple Columns

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to use Query function and it was functioning well at first. I initially only had 7 columns. However, when I tried to use to my document with up Column AZ, it is not working anymore.

This was the formula I used:

`=QUERY({'Trial Data 1'!A2:H;'Trial Data 2'!A2:H;'Trial Data 3'!A2:H},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)`

This was the formula for my other doc with up to column AZ that resulted to Parse Error:

`=QUERY({'Trial Data 1'!A2:AZ;'Trial Data 2'!A2:AZ;'Trial Data 3'!A2:AZ},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)`

Also, is there a way that only the data of selected columns will show? For example, only columns **A, B, G, H, J, K,** etc. will show?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps Stack Exchange! It would be best if you could share a copy of your spreadsheet with realistic data. As for your second question, [simply use a comma-separated list to choose which columns you want to show](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#select).

Answer (score 0):

The second formula looks fine, so chances are that you did not actually get a syntax error but an array literal error. The error is most likely caused by one or more of the sheets not actually having that many columns. Insert columns in the sheets so that column `AZ` exists on all of them.

To refer to columns A, B, G, H, J, K in your `query({array expression}`, use `"select Col1, Col2, Col7, Col8, Col10, Col12 where Col1 is not null"`.